# Как получить весь словарь mongodb, или получить его массивы? Python

Tags: python, dict, pymongo

Как мне получить весь словарь из mongodb на языке python? Или, как я могу получить все его массивы по отдельности?

Comment: А как вы кладете в базу данные? Там и смотрите метод для получения их

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for data in collection.find():
    print(data)
```